# Lock a partition to a few folders

Tags: partitioning

I want to have a few folders on a partition whose contents I can freely edit, but outside nothing should be saved.

Specifically, I want the folders in my Home (Documents, Music, etc) on a different partition, but rest of the normally hidden folders remain in the main partition with Ubuntu. I can make the files within the Home folders save in another partition using `fstab` binding, but I still can't think of how to lock the partition from edits outside those folders. I'm open to suggestions of alternatives to binding - but please, no symbolic links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want to prohibit write access - it's unclear. As user oxwivi you aren't allowed to write to /lib, /usr, /var, /bin and so on, but sudo needs write access for updates.

Or the configuration needs to changed in /etc.

And there are dynamic folders /proc /sys /dev , while logfiles are written to /var/log and so on ...

And every user needs write access to /tmp

---

(Edit after diskussion)

```
chmod a-w -R /partition
chmod u+w /partition/1 /partition/2
```

- `a-w` means 'all (user, group, others) - := remove permission to w(rite).
- `-R` means: recursively, for directories/files therein.
- `u+w` := add write-permission for the user who is owner.

In front of +and-, you may use `ugo` for user, who is the owner, group and others (problem: confusion o?owner/other) or `a` for all. 
`+-` means to add or revoke permissions, `=` means to set them.
`rwx` are acronyms for read, write and execute.

This are the mostly used ones. More details in `man chmod`.

```
chmod ug+rw foo.txt
```

adds read-write permissions for user and group.

```
chmod o=x bar.txt
```

sets the permission to execute for others.

Comment: Let's say that `/partition` is the directory to the partition in question. I don't want anything to be able to be written except inside the folders named `1` and `2`. So the only way I can write something to the partition is by saving inside `/partition/1` and `/partition/2` - nothing will be written directly to `/partition/` directory.

Comment: `chmod a-w -R /partition`, `chmod u+w  /partition/1 /partition/2` - where is the problem?

Comment: @user unknown, the problem is that I did not know how to do it. And what's the difference between your commands and the ones in Amey's answer? There seems to be slight difference in the flags used.

Comment: `u=rwx` means: for the user who is the owner, **set** the permissions to r(ead), w(rite) and (e)x(ecute). `a-w` means 'all (user, group, others) - := remove permission to w(rite). -R means: recursively, for directories/files therein. u+w := add write-permission for the user who is owner.

Comment: @user unknown, please edit that into your answer - I don't want any users to read or write unlike the other answer. And will this permission setting affect live sessions?

Comment: I did. Modifications take effekt immediately, as well in live sessions. You may need to use `sudo` if you start with insufficient permissios.

Answer (score 2):

You can give write access to these two fonder only. Apart from that do no give write access. So that user will not able to write elsewhere.

I would suggest you to give write access to partition1/folder1 and folder2.

```
chmod u=rwx partition1/folder1
chmod u=rwx partition1/folder2
```

Then I would suggest you to remove write access to partition1 folder

```
chmod u=rx partition1
```

Now you can not create any thing inside partition1 but you will be able to write into partition1/folder1 and 2.

```
xyz@xyz-desktop:~$ ls -lart|grep test1
dr-xr-xr-x  4 xyz xyz   4096 2011-03-03 19:51 test1
xyz@xyz-desktop:~$ ls test1
test3  test4
xyz@xyz-desktop:~$ ls -lart test1
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 61 xyz xyz 4096 2011-03-03 19:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 xyz xyz 4096 2011-03-03 19:51 test4
dr-xr-xr-x  4 xyz xyz 4096 2011-03-03 19:51 . 
drwxr-xr-x  2 xyz xyz 4096 2011-03-03 19:51 test3
xyz@xyz-desktop:~$ touch ./test1/willItCreate
touch: cannot touch `./test1/willItCreate': Permission denied
xyz@xyz-desktop:~$ touch ./test1/test3/willItCreate
```

Comment: Will it affect Windows?

Comment: Windows is not linux, so Windows won't really care about those permissions.

Comment: @Roland, oh right, Windows won't even read `ext` filesystems in the first place. And next time you comment, please do tag @[user] or they'll miss the reply. And will the permission affect access from live sessions as well?

Comment: @Oxwivi Unfortunately not, live sessions can access everything on the device, because in a simple way of putting it, the live session does not know who the users on the drives are, and doesn't pay much attention to them.

Comment: @Roland, can it not be made to lock writing in the partition to all users? i.e. the lock does not specify any particular user, it's simply inaccessible to all.

Comment: @Oxwivi, with a livecd, it will still be able to access the drive to my knowledge, it's simply that way because a live cd is meant to allow for recovery etc, and needs to read the drives in case of installing. If you are trying to hide something, you might be better off not having it at all :D! (joking).

Comment: @Oxwivi drwxr-xr-x permission of test4 is having write access to particular user only. All other users will not have write access.

Comment: @Amey, I don't want write access for any users. @Roland, nah, it's not for hiding something - I mentioned in my question I want to have the my files in Home in a different partition instead of assigning the entire Home. So basically, I don't want live sessions accidentally wiping it off.

Comment: @Oxwivi dr-xr-xr-x - test1 does not have write access to anybody. So does that solve your problem.

Comment: @Amey, thanks for your answer, it works, but I chose user known's answer because it also works and also explained basic `chmod` functions. Sorry, and thanks for all the help!